# Using RDFLIB to fetch elements for every class

Tags: python, rdf, owl, rdflib

I have an OWL RDF data file that contains several data such as the following example:

```
<!-- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OGMS_0000014 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OGMS_0000014">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OGMS_0000123"/>
        <obo:IAO_0000115 xml:lang="en">A representation that is either the output of a clinical history taking or a physical examination or an image finding, or some combination thereof.</obo:IAO_0000115>
        <obo:IAO_0000117>Albert Goldfain</obo:IAO_0000117>
        <obo:IAO_0000119>http://ontology.buffalo.edu/medo/Disease_and_Diagnosis.pdf</obo:IAO_0000119>
        <obo:IAO_0000232>creation date: 2010-07-19T10:18:02Z</obo:IAO_0000232>
        <rdfs:label>clinical finding</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Class>
```

and need to extract only the strings following the **rdfs:label** and the **<obo:IAO_0000115 xml:lang="en">** tags for each class.

I am successfully reading the RDF file as follows:

```
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef
g = Graph()
g.parse("ogms_20210819.owl")
```

and then loop through it as usual:

```
# Loop through each triple in the graph (subj, pred, obj)
for subj, pred, obj in g:
    print(subj, pred, obj)
```

but I'm not understanding how to fetch only the text from the two tags I need for each class.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: either you get all class URIs in a first iteration and then for each class the two properties or what I'd suggest is to use SPARQL

Comment: `prefix owl: <...> prefix rdfs: <...> prefix obo: <...> select * where {?cls a owl:Class ; rdfs:label ?label ; obo:IAO_0000115 ?val }` - don't forget to put the prefix namespace into the query

Comment: Thanks, in the second comment do I understand that you suggest I Ioad my data into a SPARQL endpoint and use the queries on them? Not sure I understand how to go on to do the first suggestion though, very ignorant of the RDFlib library :(

Comment: So the full query that you suggested works well:

PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>

select * where {?cls a owl:Class ; rdfs:label ?label ; obo:IAO_0000115 ?val}

I loaded the data into Jena Fuseki and the query is great. Now need to understand how to get this into a dataframe or other handy python structure. Thanks